# Should nested lock requests be avoided?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, locking, buffer

I have a java class which receives inputs from the outside (i.e., many threads which run concurrently), and then stores inputs into two circular buffers. These buffers work together to carry out the same job and differ only by their level of priority. That is, the buffers are named "primary" and "secondary": when an input arrives, the primary buffer is checked first, and in case it is full the secondary buffer is checked. Should even the secondary buffer be full, the input waits for a slot in one of the buffers to be available. I thought I could manage the concurrency by first locking access on the primary buffer, and requesting lock for the secondary buffer only if necessary and while still holding the previous lock.
I don't know why but something sounds strange to me. Is holding two locks at the same time a good/safe pratice as long as it doesn't lead to deadlocks or heavy starvation scenarios?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: As long as locks *are acquired in the same order* then deadlocks are not possible. I would recommend a simple "working" approach first, hidden behind an interface contract - I'm a big fan of the queues provided by [the concurrent package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) for passing data between threads.

Comment: you better describe your goals and ask if managing 2 ring buffers is a good practice for them. I suspect single buffer with united capacity would do better.

Comment: Using two distinct circular buffer is compulsory (I'm dealing with an exam exercise which explicitly requests that the buffers be two), and my goal is exactly what aforementioned: taking an input from the threads and storing it.

Comment: Why not just have one lock protect the two-buffer system?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot guarantee that the two locks are always acquired in the same order, this risks deadlock.
If you can guarantee that the outer lock will always be held when entering the inner lock, the inner lock is redundant. (*)
If you can guarantee that if code holds the inner lock, no other code will ever request the outer lock, then this does not incur deadlock. However, this is fragile, because now you are reasoning about code that is usually pretty far away. Unless there is an outer-outer lock that guarantees that the outer lock isn't acquired concurrently, but then you are back to one of the two above situations.

So yes you should avoid nested locks: Either you get deadlock, or it is useless, or you have a fragile system.

(*) There is an exception here: If the outer-locked code region starts threads which coordinate using the inner lock, this does not apply.
This kind of code is pretty rare, and so different from the nested-lock scenarios you see in practice, that I am even reluctant to call this a nested lock even though it is, technically.